# Getting two different click methods to work inside single Jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I can't get these two different click functions to work at the same time. Today is my first time using JS in any significant way, so please bear with me. I have a `selectable` Jquery list and once one of its items is selected, I want the user to be able to click a submit button. So far, the list is working but I can't get the submit button to run its code.

```
  $(function () {
      var user_id;

      $("#selectable_<%=request.id.to_s%>").selectable({
          selected: function (event, ui) {
              var result = $("#select-result-<%=request.id.to_s%>").empty();

              $(ui.selected).addClass("ui-selected").siblings().removeClass("ui-selected").each(
                      function (key, value) {
                          $(value).find('*').removeClass("ui-selected");
                      }
              );

              var index = $("#selectable_<%= request.id.to_s %> .ui-widget-content").html();
              user_id = $("#selectable_<%= request.id.to_s %> .ui-widget-content #user_id").html();
              result.append(( index ));
              alert('User selected');
          }
      });

      $("#submit_button").submit(function () {
          if (user_id) {
              //Passing mdate and phone variables to rails controller(book_date & phone)
              window.open(location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/' + "completes/create?&doer=" + user_id, "_self");
              alert("passed");
          }
          else {
              alert("Please select a user.");
          }
      });
  });
```

I tried moving the submit code above the selectable, and that stopped the selectable from functioning. So obviously it's only letting me run one of these methods at a time. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** I changed the function to .click, but still no luck.

I didn't mention this before, but I'm using Rails. But I thought I'd be fine using a simple HTML button tag, because I just need it to execute the JS. Could this have something to do with the problem?

Anyways, I've tried changing the button to Rails, and here's what I have now:

```
<%= button_tag "Submit", :id => "submit_button", :class => "btn btn-small btn-inverse",    :type => "button" %>
```

Also, this is all happening within a Bootstrap modal.

Comment: is the `#submit_button` added dynamically?

Comment: what is the submit function... I've not seen that.

Comment: @Hogan `submit()` function is the event when an HTML5 `<button></button>` or HTML `<input type="submit">` inside a form is clicked, check out the documentation from jQuery => http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: @AminJafari - I'm guessing he does not have the `<input type="submit"/>` in his code.

Comment: @Hogan possible, or maybe as Kyle said in the answer below, he does have it, but not in a form

Comment: Hogan's right, I don't have it setup as an input or in a form, so I guess that might be the problem. It's just a simple <button> tag, and I added #submit_button as an ID. Though I tried using .click, and that didn't work either. But I'll try changing it to an input tag and get back to you.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the submit button's `submit()` handler to a `click()` handler.

```
 $("#submit_button").click(function (e) {

     // in case your button is of type "submit", prevent default submit action
     e.preventDefault();

          if (user_id) {
              //Passing mdate and phone variables to rails controller(book_date & phone)
              window.open(location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/' + "completes/create?&doer=" + user_id, "_self");
              alert("passed");
          }
          else {
              alert("Please select a user.");
          }
 });
```

`submit()` only works for `forms`.